# Everything is black and pink. How to fix it?

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

I tried to load the Terrain Sample Editor, after that several components in the Package Manager gave errors and needed to be updated, I updated and everything turned pink, I tried in
Render Pipeline Converter to press something, but it only got worse and now everything is black and there is not even a Skybox
How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Well as you probably know pink means missing component, so these errors that you got could be either missing element or an element that requires different version, like in a certain unity it changed something and some shader code doesnt work or needs higher version of unity to run that shader